# flatpak app dock icon

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-dock, flatpak

If I install software as a flatpak app, to use it I have to start it from the shell like this `flatpak run org.name.appname`

How do I add an icon for that to ubuntu dock? 
I can make a script like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
flatpak run org.audacityteam.Audacity
```

but then, how do I add this shell script to dock?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a file in `$HOME/.local/share/applications/audacity.desktop` with this content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=Audacity
Exec=/usr/bin/flatpak run org.audacityteam.Audacity
Icon=__path_to_the_icon_on_your_filesystem__
```

After that the launcher will appear in dash: press super (windows) and type "audacity" and launch the application. While audacity is running right click on its icon on dock and choose "Add To Favorites".